# Magento 2 : How to add observer in core module?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I would like to add a new Observer class in module-checkout and also add this new observer in etc/events.xml.

What is the appropriate way to achieve that?

Comment: check this --- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Comment: I don't know where to put my observer file and how to define it.

Comment: Create events.xml is  Vendor/Module/etc/{scope}/events.xml  , now add the observer boilerplate in this file change it as per your requirement

Comment: I think we should never modify vendor file...

Comment: check this link --- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-events-observers/ and check events.xml file and you event name tag add core event name and after you create create an Observer file...